# Export distribution group members and description of each member to CSV

Tags: powershell, active-directory, distribution

I am interested in exporting all members of a particular distribution group to a `.csv` file and also listing the 'job title' field of each user from Active Directory.

I somewhat understand the usage of `Get-DistributionGroup` in order to accomplish the first part of this task, but how might I also query and export the 'job title' field of each user in this group?

Answer (score 0):

You really need to take a [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) of Stack Overflow. Going to help you out anyway because we are a nice bunch here.

```
$DLAlias = "Your DL list"
$DL = Get-DistributionGroupMember  "$DLAlias"

$output = Foreach($user in $DL){
    Get-ADUser $User.Name -Properties SamAccountName, mail, Description | select SamAccountName, mail, Description
}
$output | export-csv "C:\Temp\$DLAlias Members.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

Answer (score 0):

Input the name of your distribution list group, and the directory to export the file:

```
$ExportDirectory = "\\Path\to\folder"
$DistributionList = "Name of Distr List"

# Get Members, pipe to filter by User objects, pipe to get AD User objects, store in members variable
$Members = $(Get-DistributionGroupMember -Identity "$DistributionList") |
Where-Object { $_.ObjectClass -eq "User" } |
Foreach { Get-ADUser $_.SAMAccountName -Properties Title }

# Output members of list to CSV
$Members | Export-Csv "$ExportDirectory\$DistributionList.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

When you open the file you should see the user objects that are members of the distribution group.